# Вопрос про input type="file"

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Добрый день. Использую *CSS Framework Bootsrap*, прототип сайта можно посмотреть [здесь](http://vv.vipvizitka.in.ua/po/index2.html). (нужно прокрутить страницу в самый низ)
Столкнулся с проблемой:

```
<li>
<label>Вставить фоновое изображение:</label>
<input type="file" class="btn btn-primary">
</li>
```

Как мне применить `class="btn btn-primary"` только к кнопке "Выберите файл", а не ко всему полю формы?

Comment: Большое спасибо, всем, за ответы!!

Comment: @eprivalov1, велкам! Пардон, что на чистейшем английском )))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще то ни как. Попробуй лучше что то типа такого решения [JQuery плагин для стилизации файл-инпутов](http://savvateev.org/blog/38/)

Answer (score 3):

Никак. Кнопка - это неотъемлемая часть поля <input type="file" /> и не является самостоятельным элементом. Однако, можно сделать псевдокнопку, клик по которой будет триггером на поле type=file. Вот на нее и можно повесить класс и как-то стилизовать её, к примеру.

P.S. Вот [набросал вам примерчик](http://jsfiddle.net/HGK6W/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Стандартными средствами сделать это не получится. Я встречал два подхода для стилизации input type file. Расскажу мат часть, чтобы проще было осознать, если возьметесь.

**Первый:** превратить всю конструкцию (поле и кнопку) в просто кнопку. Это много неудобной, крайне-геморройной верстки. Далее добавить обычный input type text рядом. По клику на новую кнопку и выбору файла получать имя файла и вставлять в input type text.

Визуально это похоже на то, чего вы хотите достичь. Работает, конечно, не так как нетронутый input tipe file. Нельзя, например, ручками поправить путь к файлу. Более-менее опытных пользователей это будет сбивать с толку так как не видно пути к загружаемому файлу в форме и т.д.

**Второй:** Так же превратить конструкцию в кнопку. По выбору файла, рядом с кнопокой отображать имена загруженных файлов и крестик для отмены загрузки файла.

Выглядит это не стандартно, за то не сбивает с толку.

По обоим способам есть много готовых решений, JQuery-плагинов и статей, как сделать самому.

Советую еще раз подумать, надо ли вам стилизовать этот input type file.